# How to catch warning in app for Crash reporting: Received Memory Warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, warnings, crash-reports

sometimes i am facing a "Received Memory Warning" in Console. see here:

```
2012-07-13 11:39:54.344 PROJ42 [25255:707] Received memory warning.
```

The app doesnt crash.  But i want to solve this warning.
Is there a way to find out why i am getting this warning and sending a report?
if yes, how can i do that?

**Information:** i know that i can run with instruments to find such warnings. But i want to know if it is possible to catch this warning on a device from enduser?

How can i catch such warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is no build-in way to know what happened...

You can try to save some *indicative* `NSString` for each place where you allocate new objects/open new resources (like "*mainView::createNewImage => alloc*" or "*mainView::createNewImage => loading resource*") and then make a NSLog of content of that string inside

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

It may take time but can indicate you the place of problem.

Answer (score 2):

In `UIViewController` there is a method you can overwrite that is called :

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

This is the method that gets called and in which you can write your custom code.

Comment: i know this method. but how can i catch the warning message? sometimes there is Warning Level=1 and so on. Or some more informations **WHY** i am getting the warning.

Comment: As far as i know there is no way to find out why the memory is low , the method has no arguments either.

Comment: This warning will also be sent when the app os running in the background and other apps require more memory. So you should always implement this method and free up as much memory as possible. This does not necessarily indicate that your app is consuming too much memory. There is also no way to find out if your app will be killed after such a warning, no matter which warning level it has. And it might be killed when in background even though the warning level is set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Memory warnings occurs due to usage of lots of Memory in your application. Try to release the memory.