# Receiving memory warning in my iphone application.

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I am using ios camera and upload the image to our server when i cross more then 40 images i got memory warning, also my application quits automatically, i cant to solve this problem anybody help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post some code, how you are uploading the image data to server?

Comment: Just assuming you must be using the UIImageView to display your images. Are you releasing those UIImageView's?

Answer (score 1):

check out these links:

[I received memory warning and my app crashed. Does it kill autorelease objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965749/i-received-memory-warning-and-my-app-crashed-does-it-kill-autorelease-objects)

[How to catch warning in app for Crash reporting: Received Memory Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468090/how-to-catch-warning-in-app-for-crash-reporting-received-memory-warning)

[Memory warning and crash: how to handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377887/memory-warning-and-crash-how-to-handle-it)

http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2012/04/testing-memory-warnings-in-ios-applications/